# Executing multiple queries with single PS

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

i have created prepared statement object .
now i want to get the result of multiple queries . is it possible to do using single prepared statement object/ find the piece code below

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;    

String moviedirectorQry = "SELECT movie_director FROM movies WHERE movie_title= ?";
ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(moviedirectorQry);

ps.setString(1, "Twilight");

ResultSet rs=null;

rs = ps.executeQuery(moviedirectorQry);

while (rs.next()) {
    String director_name = rs.getString("movie_director");
    System.out.println("director name : " + director_name);
}
```

now i want to run another query.. how to do

Comment: in your example you are using just one query? did you try to use multiple?

Comment: i have mentioned about one query but i want to use multiple queires

Answer (score 2):

If the idea is to use the same `PreparedStatement` for different queries of the same type with only parameters' value that change, yes it is possible, simply call [`clearParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#clearParameters--) first to clear the parameters in case you want to reuse it before setting the new parameters' value.

The code could be something like that:

```
if (ps == null) {
    // The PreparedStatement has not yet been initialized so we create it
    String moviedirectorQry = "SELECT movie_director FROM movies WHERE movie_title= ?";
    ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(moviedirectorQry);
} else {
    // The PreparedStatement has already been initialized so we clear the parameters' value
    ps.clearParameters();
}
ps.setString(1, someValue);
ResultSet  rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

**NB:** You are supposed to use `executeQuery()` not `ps.executeQuery(moviedirectorQry)` otherwise the provided parameters' value will be ignored such that the query will fail.

Comment: so you mean to say evrytime i have to use the if condition i mean for each query?

Comment: You need to know whether you reuse the PS or not, in order to clear the parameters if you reuse it.

Comment: Using `executeQuery(String)` on a `PreparedStatement` (or `CallableStatement`) **must** throw an `SQLException` since JDBC 4, before that it was an implicit assumption that an implementation would disallow it. Also, technically it is not necessary to call `clearParameters()` before reusing, but if you don't set all parameters, then you could be reusing values of a previous execution.